# How to capture a text value from an UI label / Textfield using accessibility ID in EarlGrey?

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest, earlgrey

I am using EarlGrey framework but not sure which will be the method used to capture text value from an UI lable/ Textfield when using accessibility ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grey_accessibilityID("")` Like so:

```
class MyFirstEarlGreyTest: XCTestCase {

  func testExample() {

    EarlGrey
      .select(elementWithMatcher: grey_accessibilityID("phone_number_text_field"))
      .assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())
      .perform(grey_replaceText("1234"))
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Glenn, actually with accessibility ID I want to fetch the value inside a label or a textfield.

Comment: I don't think you can do that :/

Comment: You can create a custom matcher and then extract the value using it. Take a look at the FunctionalTests project for more info.

Comment: In which part of the functional test project, thanks